# How to upload file in selenium webdriver using PhantomJS in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to upload a file in headless browser. For firefox driver sendkeys is working for me but for phantomjs sendkeys doesn't work for me.

```
 // Works for FirefoxDriver
 // Doesn't work for PhantomjsDriver
 IWebElement UploadResourceBrowseButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("files"));
 UploadResourceBrowseButton.SendKeys("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");
```

Tried another solution for Phantomjs but doesn't work

```
 // Tried this as well but doesn't work
 ((PhantomJSDriver)driver).ExecutePhantomJS("var page = this; page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing input[type=file] to input[type=\"file\"]